# Is MonitorEnter time consuming operation?

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface, dalvik

I am not talking about time to take to enter synchronize block.
I am talking about time to take to execute MonitorEnter and MonitorExit statement.
And, how can I measure time to take to execute statement in C(JNI)?
I am developing Android app using Eclipse and OSX.

Comment: Uhm ... `MonitorEnter` *is* the operation that starts a `synchronize` block. So how can you talk about one, but not the other? Also: the exact timing depends on a lot of things: implementation, is the lock contested, can it be optimized away entirely, ...

Comment: And last but not least: The Dalvik VM is *quite* different from the Java VM, *especially* when it comes to low-level details and optimizations such as this. Keep that in mind when reading answers that talk about HotSpot or other Java VMs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When dealing with an uncontested lock, the current version of Dalvik uses a fast path that avoids heavyweight thread synchronization operations. In terms of speed, it's probably about the same as calling a short CPU-bound method written in the Java programming language.

If the lock is contested (that is, two or more threads are interacting with it), then this ends up being a much heavier-weight operation, bottoming out of the VM as calls to the underlying OS's thread library. That said, it's typical to expect the time spent doing heavyweight thread operations to be dominated by the actual activity being locked (because if the activity weren't relatively long-running, you wouldn't have been so likely to have a contested lock in the first place).

As always, profiling can help you figure this all out.

If you want to peek under the covers, you can find the salient code in `platform/dalvik/vm/Sync.cpp>` in the Android sources. Look for `dvmLockObject`, though you'll have to wander into the JIT compiler code to get a more complete story.